# Calling Specific function of a class in php service using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, service

I m very new to php programming and may not be good in framing questions. but help me in this. 
am calling a javascript method on button click. in that method am calling a php Service method through Ajax. My code looks like.

```
 function callServiceMethod(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        async : true,
        url : "../Controller/login_controller.php",
        data : $("#login_form").serialize(),
        success : function(response)
        {
        //how to hold response on conditional check here?   
        },
        error : function()
        {

        }
    }); 
}
```

ps: am not using any framework like zend, and don't want to use as of now.(to learn basics) 
now the problem is

my login_controller.php has two methods, checkuser() and  checkpassword(). Please help me with the following.

my controller class looks as follows

```
<?php 

require_once '../Model/login_model.php';
?>

<?php
    ob_start();

    class login_controller
    {

        public function checkuser()
        {
            return $_POST['uname'];
        }

        public function checkpassword()
        {
            return $_POST["pass"];
        }
    }

    $obj = new login_controller();
    $obj->checkuser(); // this i want to remove, which should be directly called from ajax call
    $obj->checkpassword();
?>
```

1. how can i call a particular function of a controller from above ajax call
2. how to decide on "datatype"(when to use text,html,JSON etc)
3. how i should capture response sent from my controller in my ajax success Block.
4. Please provide me a useful resource (books,online tutorial,sample code) which can help me in my purpose.
   it wil be great to  have answers.
    thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. So remove point 4 - sorry.

Comment: ya Sure @Unihedron was actually looking forward for some help so i just put it out. sorry